# PayPal Error "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment, paypal-subscriptions

Please help me with this PayPal Error.

I have tried various solutions that I found over stackoverflow. I tried using POST method but still the same. My credentials are correct. I also tried fixing encryption settings found in the blog but they were fine too.

It works fine when it's single payment processing but if it's a subscription then I get this error. It was working fine the day before yesterday.

Please let me know, what can be the issue.

I am also attaching the error snippet below:

[image]

Comment: In my case I was sending the amount to 10 and discount is 10 too, so it was an error in my form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue, by two ways

1. Just remove browser cookies and change the API keys of PayPal,
   (client key and secret key).
2. This issue from the PayPal side just wait for time.